# pass by reference and const function

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Basically I need to change the Two StudentType* functions to const but i know its not letting me because of the &ampersand sign on the ReadStudentData function, is there anyway around this?

I am not asking for someone to do my hw just point me in right direction

it brings up a whole bunch of errors when I try to throw const in it

this is what i am trying to get:

```
StudentType * SortStudentByName(const StudentType* student, int size);

void ReadStudentData(ifstream& infile, StudentType*& student,
                     int& numOfStudents)
{
    string firstName, lastName;
    int testScore;
    int count = 0;

    infile >> numOfStudents;

    try {
        student = new StudentType[numOfStudents];
        while (infile >> firstName >> lastName >> testScore) {
            if (testScore >= 0 && testScore <=100) {
                student[count].studentName = lastName + ", " + firstName;
                student[count].testScore = testScore;
                count++;
            }
        }
        numOfStudents = count;
    } catch (bad_alloc) {
        cout << "Failed to allocate memory" << endl;
        numOfStudents = 0;
        student = NULL;
    }
}


StudentType* SortStudentsByName(StudentType* student, int numStudents) {
    int startScan, minIndex;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (numStudents-1); startScan++) {
        minIndex = startScan;
        for (int index = startScan; index < numStudents; index++) {
            if (student[index].studentName < student[minIndex].studentName)
                minIndex = index;
        }
        StudentType temp = student[minIndex];
        student[minIndex] = student[startScan];
        student[startScan] = temp;    
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "List of Students sorted Alphabetically "<< endl;
    DisplayAllStudents(student, numStudents);

    return student;
}

StudentType* SortStudentsByScore(StudentType* student, int numStudents) {
    int startScan, minIndex;
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (numStudents-1); startScan++) {
        minIndex = startScan;
        for ( int index = startScan; index < numStudents; index++) {
            if( student[index].testScore>student[minIndex].testScore)
                minIndex = index;
        }
        StudentType temp = student[minIndex];
        student[minIndex] = student[startScan];    
        student[startScan] = temp;
    }
    cout <<"List of Students sorted by Score from Highest to Lowest" << endl;
    DisplayAllStudents(student, numStudents);
    return student;
}
```

Comment: Not surprised it complains. You assign to/thru student in both functions, and you cant assign to consts.

Comment: Why do you want to "throw in" const? Your function modifies the `StudentType` objects. It doesn't make sense to require them to be constant.

Comment: Note that `student[a] = x` means: _Modify_ the object at position `a` of the `student` array so it becomes a copy of `x`. It does _not_ mean: Replace the constant object at position `a` of the array with the constant object `x`. So what you are doing _is_ an attempt to modify a constant object, not an attempt to replace one constant object with another.

Comment: Yeah, to not modify the Students themselves, you need an array of pointers to `StudentType`, not an array of `StudentType`.

Comment: In Ruby, there's a `freeze` member function, however, it wouldn't make sense using something like that in your case.

Comment: thanks joe! this is what i need to do