# Allocating an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am having trouble allocating a new array , this is my old function it worked perfectly buy now I am trying to change it to a const

```
StudentType* SortStudentsByName(StudentType* student, int numStudents)
{
   int startScan,
   minIndex;

   for (startScan = 0; startScan < (numStudents-1); startScan++) 
   {
      minIndex = startScan;
      for ( int index = startScan; index < numStudents; index++) 
      {
         if( student[index].studentName < student[minIndex].studentName)
            minIndex = index;
      }

       if(minIndex!=startScan)
       {
           StudentType temp = student[minIndex]; 
           student[minIndex] = student[startScan];
           student[startScan] = temp;
       }
   }

   cout << endl;
   cout << "List of Students sorted Alphabetically "<< endl;
   DisplayAllStudents(student, numStudents);
   return student;
}
```

I think it has to do with the three line I commented out, this is my code:

```
StudentType* SortStudentsByName(const StudentType* student, int numStudents)    
{
   StudentType* New_StudentType;

   //Allocate a new array
   New_StudentType = new StudentType[numStudents];

   int startScan,
   minIndex;

   for (startScan = 0; startScan < (numStudents); startScan++)
   {
       minIndex = startScan;
       for ( int index = startScan; index < numStudents; index++)
       {
          if( student[index].studentName < student[minIndex].studentName)
        minIndex = index;
       }

       New_StudentType = student[minIndex]; //error 1
       student[minIndex] = student[startScan];// error 2
       student[startScan] =  New_StudentType;// error 3
   }
   cout << endl;
   cout << "List of Students sorted Alphabetically "<< endl;
   DisplayAllStudents(student, numStudents);
   return New_StudentType; 
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: please make this mess readable - remove extra linefeeds and add proper indending.

Comment: Is DisplayAllStudents expecting a const StudentType*?

Comment: Isn't this the same `const` problem you asked about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308540/pass-by-reference-and-const-function

Comment: `New_StudentType` is a `StudentType*` pointer, you are trying to assign a `StudentType` to it. That can't work.

Comment: I am sorry to say this, but your problem is exactly the same as in yesterday's question. You still attempt to modify a constant object. The newly allocated array, and your attempt to assign one member (!) of the old array to the entire new array doesn't change anything.

Comment: Post your code after you "tried changing it to a const"

Comment: Why change what wasn't broken before? why are you making it const when the function isn't going to work with it as const?

Comment: @JoseMeza Why are you trying to change it to a const: do you understand what that does, and if so, why are you surprised when the compiler complains that you are trying to change data that you have now marked as const?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your new function you have the argument:

```
const StudentType* student
```

In this case const can be on either side of the type so this is equivalent to

```
StudentType const* student
```

so `student` is a pointer to `const StudentType`. Next note that there are two ways of declaring a const pointer: one that prevents you from changing WHAT is pointed to, and one that prevents you from changing the DATA pointed to.

So in your case you may change the pointer value but you can't change the data with this pointer.

Proceeding, the first error you have listed is:

```
New_StudentType = student[minIndex]; //error 1
```

which is wrong because you try to assign the `student` data at `minIndex` to the pointer New_StudentType, these are incompatible types.

The next error you have labeled is:

```
student[minIndex] = student[startScan];// error 2
```

As noted above you may change the pointer value but not the student data, you are attempting to change the data with this statement.

Error 3 has the same issue:

```
student[startScan] =  New_StudentType;// error 3
```